# OnPressed not working inside Stack widget after Transforming a widget

Tags: flutter

In the given code,onPressed on the raised button works and translate FlatButton to the top. But onPressed on FlatButton is not working

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Transform(
          transform: Matrix4.translationValues(
            0.0,
            _translateButton.value,
            0.0,
          ),
          child: FlatButton(
            onPressed: () {
              print('tapped Flat button');
            },
            child: Text('upper'),
          ),
        ),
          RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              animate();
              print('tapped Raised button');
            },
            child: Text('lower'))
      ],
    );
  }
```

Here _translatebutton value changes from  0 to -60 when animate() is called

```
 _animationController = AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500))
      ..addListener(() {
        setState(() {});
      });
    _translateButton = Tween<double>(
      begin: 0,
      end: -60,
    ).animate(CurvedAnimation(
      parent: _animationController,
      curve: Interval(
        0.0,
        0.75,
        curve: _curve,
      ),
    ));
```

Comment: tried `AnimatedAlign`? *"Animated version of Align which automatically transitions the child's position over a given duration whenever the given alignment changes"*

Comment: @pskink I can't control the start of the animation with `AnimatedAlign`

Comment: it starts "whenever the given alignment changes"

Comment: what is working now? `Transform` with `Matrix4.translationValue`? and what button do you mean? BTW why didnt you use `Transform.translate`?

Comment: @pskink sorry, its working with AnimatedAlign But the problem is i need it to work with Transform widget. Reason: i simplified the question, I have FAB in the place of buttons and its placed in the notch, centerDocked. when using AnimatedAlign ` shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),` does not work. this is from https://medium.com/@agungsurya/create-a-simple-animated-floatingactionbutton-in-flutter-2d24f37cfbcc

Comment: https://medium.com/@agungsurya/create-a-simple-animated-floatingactionbutton-in-flutter-2d24f37cfbcc in this post author is using column instead of stack to align FAB but `shape: CircularNotchedRectangle()` does not work when using column. When i use stack its working but onTap does not work

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27587

Answer (score 2):

If your translation moves the button outside the area of the stack, the button no longer reacts to clicks. A simple way to test this is to wrap your Stack widget in a container and color it blue (or anything obvious), and if your button is moved outside the blue area, you know it's losing its clickability because it's outside of the Stack.

If this indeed is the issue, the solution is to keep the Stack inside the container, and then either set the container dimensions such that the button still stays within the border after translation, or reposition widgets relative to the container such that the translation stays within the border.

Answer (score 2):

If someone is still trying to solve this issue, I solved it by wrapping the widget with **IgnorePointer**  widget on which I don't want the pointer to reach.

reference from [here](https://flutterhq.com/questions-and-answers/1296/flutter-textfields-are-not-clickable-inside-stack)

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the Transform widget in a SizedBox (expanded or from size, depending on your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this problem last week and in my case, the composition was like this:

```
 Stack(
    children: [
      Widget0,
      Widget1,
      Opacity(
            opacity: sth,
            child: Transform.translate(
              offset: Offset(sth),
              child: Transform.rotate(
                angle:sth,
                child: FlatButton(
                  onPressed: (){sth},
                  child: Text("sth"),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
         ],
        )
```

> Based on the suggestion of ***rahulthakur319*** on the issue number
> [27587](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27587)

I wrapped my `Transform.translate` composition inside a new `Stack` and I wrapped the stack inside a `Container`. Remember that the new `Container` should have enough width and height to show its child. I personally used MediaQuery.of(context).size.
it's working even during the complex series of animations.
The final code:

```
Stack(
    children: [
      Widget0,
      Widget1,
      Opacity(
            opacity: sth,
            child: Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  Transform.translate(
                    offset: Offset(sth),
                    child: Transform.rotate(
                      angle: sth,
                      child: FlatButton(
                        onPressed: (){sth},
                        child: Text("sth"),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
         ],
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer I got was that in a View if an element is translated then the animation works correct but the click property is altered in someway that we can't use it after translating the element

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue my Switch widget was not working in the Stack.
The solution i found was to include it in SizeBox or Container with fixed width and height.
if your switch widget is in Row try to add Constraints on Row with SizeBox rather than adding it in every widget.